# Failing to + infinitive / Failing of + gerund / For lack of + noun

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I want to express the idea that if had a girlfriend, I would love to travel with her, but failing that, I will travel just by myself.

Which of the followings sounds better to you:

1. Failing to have a girlfriend, I will travel alone.
2. Failing of having a girlfriend, I will travel alone.
3. For lack of a girlfriend, I will travel alone.
4. None of these but rather something else?

Thank you

Comment: 3 is the best of your options.  2 is ungrammatical. 1 is okay but not idiomatic.  You could also say, “Failing at having a girlfriend”.  Or “For want of a girlfriend...”

Comment: You said it quite well in the question: if had a girlfriend, I would love to travel with her, but failing that, I will travel just by myself.  (You could get rid of "just" or put it before "travel.)

Comment: Hello, Kayzah. '... failing a girlfriend' is totally unidiomatic. The only example on the internet is this query. Native speakers would use 'Not having a girlfriend,' or 'As I do not have a girlfriend,'.

Answer (score 1):

Failing a girlfriend, I will travel alone. (We do not use prepositions with *fail* when it is used for "in absence of.")

EXAMPLE:

> Appointments are available on the 2nd and the 6th of this month, but failing either of those, we could fit you in on the 15th.

Comment: Hello, Vipul. Though the CED example you quote (and should link to and attribute) is certainly acceptable, 'failing a girlfriend' meaning 'lacking a girlfriend' is totally unidiomatic. The only example on the internet is this query. Native speakers would use 'Not having a girlfriend,' or 'As I do not have a girlfriend,'.

Answer (score -1):

3 means 'because I don't have a gf'. 'Failing a gf' would mean 'if I can't get a gf'. Which of these do you mean?

Comment: Given how this is a forum about proper English language usage, it would be a good idea to use complete sentences and proper words wherever possible.